# Rust string lifetimes and iterator adapters (lifetime compile error)

Tags: rust

I'm working with CSV so I need to trim newlines and split on commas for each line, and filter out any lines that have a '?' in them.

```
let instances: Vec<Vec<&str>> = file.lines()
    .map(|x| x.unwrap())
    .filter(|x| !(x.contains("?")))
    .map(|x| x.as_slice().trim_chars('\n').split_str(",").collect()).collect();
```

This is the compiler error message I'm getting:

```
.../src/main.rs:13:18: 13:19 error: `x` does not live long enough
.../src/main.rs:13         .map(|x| x.as_slice().trim_chars('\n').split_str(",").collect()).collect();
                                                             ^
.../src/main.rs:7:11: 21:2 note: reference must be valid for the block at 7:10...
.../src/main.rs:7 fn main() {
.../src/main.rs:8     let path = Path::new("./...");
.../src/main.rs:9     let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(&path));
.../src/main.rs:10     let instances: Vec<Vec<&str>> = file.lines()
.../src/main.rs:11         .map(|x| x.unwrap())
.../src/main.rs:12         .filter(|x| !(x.contains("?")))
                                            ...
.../src/main.rs:13:18: 13:72 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 13:17
.../src/main.rs:13         .map(|x| x.as_slice().trim_chars('\n').split_str(",").collect()).collect();
```

I don't understand how the lifetimes of the string types in Rust are supposed to be used in this context. Changing `instances` to `Vec<Vec<String>>` doesn't fix the problem either.

What's extra confusing to me is that following works with a single String:

```
let x: Vec<&str> = some_string.as_slice().trim_chars('\n').split_str(",").collect();
```

What am I doing wrong with the lifetime of these values to cause this compiler error?

If iterator adapters are not an idiomatic approach to this problem please explain why and how I should approach this differently.

Comment: If you want to read CSV data, then you should use a proper parser. :) https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv

Comment: @BurntSushi5: especially since splitting on `,` without taking `"` into account is such a bad idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` `&str` is a reference to the contents of a `String`, the ones yielded by `lines()`. A `&str` can only live as long as the `String` it is a reference into, and you’re not storing the `String` anywhere. You would need to either store the lines in another variable:

```
let lines = file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let instances: Vec<Vec<&str>> = lines.iter()
    .filter(|x| !(x.contains("?")))
    .map(|x| x.trim_chars('\n').split_str(",").collect()).collect();
```

Or else you would convert all of the `&str`s into `String`s:

```
let instances: Vec<Vec<String>> = file.lines()
    .map(|x| x.unwrap())
    .filter(|x| !(x.contains("?")))
    .map(|x| x.trim_chars('\n').split_str(",")
        .map(|x| x.into_string()).collect()).collect();
```

As an incidental note, the `collect()` calls can be written `collect::<Vec<_>>()`, allowing you to remove the type annotation from the `instances` variable. Which is better? Up to you to decide.

Comment: Oh wow, I tried the nested mapping way but used "to_string" instead of "into_string"...ouch.

Is there any difference in performance/memory usage between the two ways? Specifically, does the first one consume the whole collection twice due to storing the unwrapped lines before performing the other operations?

Thanks!

Comment: `to_string` and `into_string` will both work fine and are semantically equivalent; for the moment, however, `to_string` is less efficient than `into_string`, as it uses the `std::fmt` architecture which is currently overallocating rather than being precise where possible, with a minimum allocation of 128 bytes, while `into_string` skips that and is precise. I’m hoping `to_string` will be fixed in the future but I don’t know for sure.